# Locally Persist data in browser

Tags: json, browser, local-storage, elm

I am exploring elm to create the sample application, I want to store some data in the local storage of browser.

Currently i am working on 0.17.1 version. so any one please help me to solve this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TodoMVC implementation actually gives you a fair example how you can access localstorage via ports.  I suggest you to take a look.

https://github.com/evancz/elm-todomvc

Answer (score 1):

As of today there are no modules published on the official package repository, do it through Ports for now.

---

If you feel adventurous and really want to get it to work asap, you can use [fredcy/localstorage](https://github.com/fredcy/localstorage)

#### Here's how you hack it

Clone [fredcy/localstorage](https://github.com/fredcy/localstorage) in the root of your project.

You will probably want to remove the VCS root.

Add [elm-lang/dom](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/dom/1.0.0/Dom-LowLevel) as a dependency to your project.

```
$ git clone git@github.com:fredcy/localstorage.git
$ rm -rf localstorage/.git
$ elm package install elm-lang/dom -y
```

Add the following to your `./elm-package.json`:

```
"source-directories": [
    ".",
    "localstorage/src",
    "localstorage/src/Native"
],
"native-modules": true,
```

And the worst part, go in to `localstorage/src/Native/LocalStorage.js` and replace:

```
3 // var _fredcy$localstorage$Native_LocalStorage = function()
4 var _user$project$Native_LocalStorage = function()
```

#### Advantages?

Having Elm-driven API for the Local Storage might be worth the hassle, but this stuff will break in the future.

Go with Ports.